# error:https://cdn.foxycart.com/bmjpg.ecommerce.highwire.org/loader.js code:403 message:Forbidden,

Tags: jmeter-5.0

These are my request headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: iso-8859-1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Encoding: br
Host: fmch.bmj.com
```

These are my response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2024 04:22:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=900, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
Set-Cookie: SSESS5ac278cb1207db5e61ce8ffc30a9da88=0SY8wxG7C7h0_h-AHeQMEX0sqA4_Y79YY2o02cyQyLE; expires=Thu, 07-Mar-2024 06:22:51 GMT; path=/; domain=.bmj.com; secure; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Language: en
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Highwire-Login: login-page
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Etag: W/"1709785371-1"
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Mar 2024 04:22:51 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
X-Highwire-Sitecode: fmch
X-HighWire-SMART-Code: fmch_production
X-Varnish: 2052633496
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Varnish-TTL: 
X-Varnish-Cache: 
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 8607ce8c4c5b5987-DEL
```

I have provided the valid username and password after that I'm found this type of error please help me out

Like this

```
UN- ddt
PW- i2pqfq0yz
```

When I hit the userls by jmeter than the API is breaking also under this API

[image]